# Reloading only one UITableViewCell on a UITableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios

Ok Guys, here's the situation I have.

I'm using a UITableViewController with Core Data.  The table has about 200 cells, that basically function as a checklist.  When you tap a cell, that cell has a checkbox that gets toggled set to the UITableViewCell.imageView ( the UIImageView assigned to the left of the label).

Anytime I use either of the two ways below to update the table, it takes about 1 - 2 seconds for the update ... and from what I can tell, it seems to be reloading every cell. How can I force only the cell that was just tapped to be updated?

`[self.tableView reloadData];` or

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:NO];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:NO];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:NO];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:NO];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                    atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:NO];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:NO];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: How do you update the data in the model? It sounds like all the cells get updated.

Comment: the second parameter of `-insertSections:withRowAnimation:`, `-deleteSections:withRowAnimation:`, `-insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`, and `-deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` are not `BOOL`; they are a `UITableViewRowAnimation` type

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need this:

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW40

Comment: I actually found this a few minutes after posting the question and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just updating the cell's textlabel text- this code is enough

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (int)_targetMaxDistanceSlider.value];
```