# Semi-Transparent UITableViewCells are not transparent until they have been scrolled off screen

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

**[FIXED]**
After trying quite a few different solutions I finally got one to work.  All I needed to do was set the cell backgroundColor to clear in the willDisplayCell method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

My UITableview has a background image (Photo) and the cells in the table view have a semi-transparent background.

When i first show the UITableView the cells are not showing as transparent.  But as soon as I scroll a cell off screen and scroll it back on the cell displays with the semi-transparent background.

Does anyone have any clues as to why it doesn't display correctly until the cell is scrolled off screen?  See attached images.  First one shows the tableview as soon as its loaded. and the second image shows what it looks like after scrolling the top few cells off screen and back on again.

[image: Initial state of tableview. The cells are not showing semi-transparent]
[image: Top3 cells have been scrolled off screen and back on again and display how I want them to]

Below is the code I'm using to setup the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellPhotoIdentifier = @"PhotoDescriptionCell";


      UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellPhotoIdentifier] autorelease];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Photo description %i", indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.opaque = NO;
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.contentView.opaque = NO;
    cell.contentView.alpha = 0.7;
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 

    return cell;
}
```

I'm using XCode 4 with IOS SDK 4.3

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281515/how-to-customize-the-background-color-of-a-uitableviewcell/1220985#1220985)

Comment: I had tried that before, I tried setting the transparency in the willDisplayCell function but it still didn't work.  But I just tried it again and just set the cell backgroundColor to [UIColor clearColor] and its now working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After re-reading the answer that @progrmr gave the link for, I tried again and managed to get it to work.

I needed to set the Cell Background Color to clear in the **willDisplayCell** method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Comment: thanks for this, i tried setting background color and removing background views and just about everything, but this did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you are loading the cells first, and then setting them to be transparent once they are already loaded. Then once you scroll them off screen and back on, they are transparent because you have forced them to be reloaded with the correct settings.

You can fix this buy changing the cell properties in Interface Builder to have the cells be transparent from the start, or after you configure the cell, you need to add code that forces the cell to reload itself. Let me try to find that, as I don't know off the top of my head.

This question should help you figure out cell reloading: [Reloading only one UITableViewCell on a UITableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485162/reloading-only-one-uitableviewcell-on-a-uitableview)

Comment: @progrmr pointed me back to a post I had read, and after trying some suggestions in that I managed to fix my problem.  I've edited the question to include the fix.

Comment: @Craig Mellon: Instead of editing your question, post an answer with your solution and accept it so it is clear the question is no longer open.

Comment: Will do, I just tried it but I have to wait 8 hours before answering my own question.  Thanks for the heads up, i'll answer it in 8 hours :)