# Showing a indicator view on top of a table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

When processing some data in the background which is specific to a table view cell, I would like to put the table view cell's view in a semi-transparent mode and put a progress indicator view on top of the table view cell.

I tried the following code, but no activity indicator is shown:

```
-(void)showActivityIndicatorInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.frame];
  view.tag = 50;

  UIActivityIndicatorView *ac = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
     initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
  CGRect frame = view.frame;
  ac.center = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, frame.size.height/2);
  [view addSubview:ac];
  [ac startAnimating];
}
```

What is wrong with my code? What would be a better way to implement this? How could I show the indicator view in a semi-transparent view which overlays the table view cell?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, you're never adding the UIView you created to your cell. You might want to do the following:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:view];
```

Also, you might want to change the frame of the view you add to your cell to something different than the actual cell. This will allow you to scroll within your `UITableView` without disturbing the worker view you setup.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, cell.contentView.frame.size.height)];
```

To make the view semi-transparent:

```
[view setOpaque:YES];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5]];
```

Comment: I really did forget to add the subview to the content view. Thank you for pointing me to this error! In addition, I did not set the activity indicator color to a different color than white. As my background is white, the indicator view was not visible.

Comment: Please read @dasblinkenlight's answer. He's got a very valid point. You'll still need what I put in my answer to get it to work the way you want though.

Comment: I used both answers to get to my solution, it works great now. Do you have any suggestion on how to make the view semi-transparent when the indicator view is shown?

Comment: Yes, you can make the UIView opaque and set the background color to white with a 50% opacity. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, it is not a good idea to mess around with `UITableViewCell` objects owned by a `UITableView` from the outside, because the cell that you are going to get may get recycled after being scrolled off the screen, so even if you add an activity indicator, it may get removed.

A better approach is to let your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` handle the additions and removals of the activity indicator. For that your model needs to keep a registry of index paths on which the activity indicator should be displayed (the "registry" could be as simple as a single variable, if you never turn on the activity indicator on several cells at the same time). The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should read that registry, and decorate the cell accordingly. When you want to add an activity indicator, add the corresponding index path to the registry, and call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` on the table view. When you need to turn off the activity indicator, remove the index path of the cell from the registry, and reload the row again.

Essentially, the model needs to be the keeper of the state. Everything that has to do with altering `UIView` subclasses needs to happen in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Finally, the controller should give your table view "a tap on the shoulder" when the state needs to change.

Comment: Thank you for your great advice on putting the code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and using a separate `NSArray? to register the index paths of table view cells which should show an indicator view. In combination with the hints Simon gave me in his answer, I got this now working. Do you have any suggestion on how to make the view semi-transparent when the indicator view is shown?

Comment: @AlexR Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7123118/335858) for hints at how to make cells semi-transparent. Please be careful with cell transparency, because it may significantly slow down your table's scrolling speed.