# Reload sections in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am writing an app that notifies user when its time to take his/her medicine. The label at the top of the page shows a date and the `tableView` gets populated with medicine names and times that need to be taken on that particular day. Now the sections get populated on the basis of number of medicines to be taken on that day. So the number of sections are dynamically changing over time; a medicine is scheduled to be taken on that particular day. Whenever the user takes a medicine, it is stored in DB as a variable that changes to `"1"` else it remains `"0"`.

Also I know that I need to reload section of that particular medicine on that day.

Now the question is how do I achieve that? How to reload a particular section?

```
for(NSManagedObject *mo in secondEntityArray) {
    NSDate *temp1 = [mo valueForKey:@"date"];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString * temp2 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:temp1];
    NSDate *temp3 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:temp2];
    NSDate * temp4 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:_dateLabel.text];
    if([temp3 compare:temp4] == NSOrderedSame) {
        if([[mo valueForKey:@"isNotificationFired"] isEqualToString:@"1"] && [[mo valueForKey:@"repeatDays"] isEqualToString:@"Everyday"]) {
            //Reflect changes in tableView section
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are few functions supported in UITableView for reloading data. See section [Reloading the Table View](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/) of doc.

- reloadData
- reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
- reloadSections:withRowAnimation:
- reloadSectionIndexTitles

Also, see [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306792/uitableview-reload-section), a part from it:

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 1);
NSIndexSet *section = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];                                     
[self.tableView reloadSections:section withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Also, it is not necessary to reload specific sections, you can just adjust your dataset and call `[tableView reloadData]`, it will load the visible cells only. A part from doc:

> Call this method to reload all the data that is used to construct the
>   table, including cells, section headers and footers, index arrays, and
>   so on. For efficiency, the table view redisplays only those rows that
>   are visible. It adjusts offsets if the table shrinks as a result of
>   the reload.

Comment: Actually I was initially loading the table view with data from first entity in core data and later I was trying to reload it from the data in second entity.I am doing all this for the first time as I am a beginner,so I really messed it up and I realised it now.I already know all those methods that you mentioned.But anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 92):

**Swift 3**

NSIndexSet is nothing special

```
tableView.reloadSections([1, 2, 3], with: .none)
```

It's just an array. Crazy.

Comment: this is great solution

Comment: you have to define the function first.... then use it. func reloadSections(_ sections: IndexSet, with animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)

Comment: Insanely easy solution

Comment: @Martian2049 it will be an existing property if you use a UITableViewController, otherwise you'll have to create an outlet to your tableview property via interface builder or instantiate one from scratch and give it a frame, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Update for quick usage in Swift (as of 2.2)

```
// index 0 being the section number 1 that you will reload
tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation: .None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to reload your section

```
- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

Comment: Dude I know the method to be used but I don't understand how to use NSIndexSet to keep track of the indexes of my sections

Comment: Create the index like this [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:yourIndexOfSectionToReload]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method, you can pass section details in  different ways

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:NO];
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Reloading particular sections improves performance for the table view as well some time it also avoid some issues like floating/moving custom headers-footers in your view.
SO try to use reloadSection than relaodData whenever possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use this also--

`indexPath.section` - `UITableView section which you want to reload .

```
 NSIndexSet *section = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section];
[self.tableView reloadSections:section withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```