# How to handle flickering and blank space issues while reloading the tableview?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin iOS and my table view contains multiple types of cells.
All the cells have dynamic height and different contents with multiple sections.

Here suppose I have total 10 cells out of which few are visible and others are hidden. Based on user action, It depends on whether to show or hide the cell.

In this scenario, If the number of cells is less, It's somehow working fine. But flickering and blank space are showing when the number of cells increases.

Comment: Can you share your sample or code?

Comment: private nfloat GetRowHeight(Type type)
        {
            if (type.IsTypeHidden)
                return 0;
            return UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
        }  .                                                                                                                   In tableview GetCell hiding the cell if row height is zero else show the cell with required height. Here all cells are of different height.

Comment: Can you add the code to you actual post for better readability? And I believe the sample you posted is too small for us to really identify the issue. Please give your post some love.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload only appropriate section or even rows instead of reload whole tableview.

Please checkout this solutions.
[Reload sections in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352070/reload-sections-in-uitableview)