# UISegmentedControl not selecting when value changes

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol, uicontrolevents

Previously I had an issue having an UISegmentedControl in tableview section header cell, and I wanted to listen to value changes in the main view controller.

I got this solved by using `addTarget` on the UISegmentedControl in the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection` method, and this works.

First segment is default selected, and this works. When tapping on second segment, it reloads the tableview with other data, which is expected behaviour. However, first segment is still selected. Which means I cannot switch back to the original data in the table view.

[Please see this video](http://recordit.co/WxUbqODDrO) and you will see what I am trying to explain.

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code?

```
/*
 * Main View Controller
 */
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    if section == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    let sectionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SegmentCell") as! SegmentTableViewCell

    // Add event for the UISegmentedControl
    sectionCell.segmentControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleSegmentControlEvent), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    return sectionCell
}

func handleSegmentControlEvent(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    self.segmentControlIndex = sender.selectedSegmentIndex

    switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {

        case 0:
            if latestTableData.count == 0 {
                loadItems("latest")
            } else {
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
            break

        case 1:
            if closestTableData.count == 0 {
                loadItems("closest")
            } else {
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
            break;

        default:
            break
    }
}

/*
 * Segment table view cell
 */
class SegmentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: if you're reloading table view, it reloads the header view also. so segment control reinitialised to previous state.

Comment: Thanks @SuryaSubenthiran! That makes alot of sense.. Is there some method to only reload specific section?

Comment: better use flag to hold the current state of segment, and use the flag to set the segment state upon initialising.

Comment: As you have already stored the current segment state, just add the line "sectionCell.segmentControl. selectedSegmentIndex=self.segmentControlIndex" in viewForHeaderInSection method.

Answer (score 2):

when tableView is reload that means `viewForHeaderInSection` is also reload. So, it is got initial stage after reloading.So you should choose different approach for it like you can add segmented control outside the tableview not as headerview or reload only rows or cells etc.

for example,

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

**Update :**

reload section,

```
 NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 1);
 NSIndexSet *section = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];                                     
 [self.tableView reloadSections:section withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

It will reload first section. For more detail you can refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306792/uitableview-reload-section)

it is objective c code convert in swift!!

hope this will help :)

Comment: This includes also the header view, correct? Is there some method for only reloading a specific section?