# How to delete userdefault data in rows in a section in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitableview

I have been trying to figure out how to solve this and I was able to delete any row but since I did not know how to delete the selected row from its `userdefault` data, it just disappeared temporarily. I have created an instance called `sections` which hold `sectionName` and `words`. I would like to access words and delete a selected one in rows in `UITableView`.  Also there is an error. The error says Type [String]! has no subscript members. It seems like there is a problem with this line;

```
removeData(index: sections[indexPath.section].words[indexPath.row])
```

And this is the code in the following;

```
 struct Section {
    var sectionName: String!
    var words: [String]!

    init(title: String, word: [String]) {
        self.sectionName = title
        self.words = word

    }
}
var sections = [Section]()
        sections = [
        Section(title: "A", word: []), // 1
        Section(title: "B", word: []), //2
        Section(title: "C", word: []),
        Section(title: "D", word: []),
        Section(title: "E", word: []),
        Section(title: "F", word: []),
        Section(title: "G", word: []),
        Section(title: "H", word: []),
        Section(title: "I", word: []),
        Section(title: "J", word: []),
        Section(title: "K", word: []),
        Section(title: "L", word: []),
        Section(title: "M", word: []),
        Section(title: "N", word: []),
        Section(title: "O", word: []),
        Section(title: "P", word: []),
        Section(title: "Q", word: []),
        Section(title: "R", word: []),
        Section(title: "S", word: []),
        Section(title: "T", word: []),
        Section(title: "U", word: []),
        Section(title: "V", word: []),
        Section(title: "W", word: []),
        Section(title: "X", word: []),
        Section(title: "Y", word: []),
        Section(title: "Z", word: [])
    ]




func getData() -> [String] {
    if let data = userdefaultData.stringArray(forKey: "data") {

        return data
    }
    return []
}


 func removeData(index: Int) {
    var data = getData()
    data.remove(at: index)
    userdefaultData.set(data, forKey: "data")
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source

        tableView.beginUpdates()

        // Delete the row from the data source
        if getData().count > 0 {
            removeData(index: sections[indexPath.section].words[indexPath.row])
        }

        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        tableView.endUpdates()



    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}
```

Comment: add one line after changes in your Nsuedefault that userDefaults.synchronize()

Comment: Error says Type [String]! has no subscript members. It seems like there is a problem with this line; removeData(index: sections[indexPath.section].words[indexPath.row])

Comment: looks like you're passing a string to a function that takes an int ? sections[indexPath.section].words[indexPath.row] should return a string

Comment: @Ryo are you trying to delete the section from the tableView or from userDefaults?

Comment: I am trying to delete a row in a section from the tableview and also userDerfault!

Answer (score 0):

As i can see, you are trying to remove a given word from your data. I would recommend to do the following:

first find the word you would like to remove, `getData.count > 0` statements body.

```
if getData().count > 0 {
        let section = sections[indexPath.section
        let word = section.words[indexPath.row]
        remove(word)
}
```

Than replace the `removeData` function with this function:

```
func remove(_ word: String) {
    var data = getData()

    // Lets search for the removeable word's index in the array
    var index = 0
    for wordCandidate in data {
        if wordCandidate == word {
            // Once found, exit from the loop
            return
        }
        // if not found, increase the index by one
        index += 1
    }
    // Remove the word at the right index
    data.remove(at: index)
    userdefaultData.set(data, forKey: "data")
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but an error said  invalid number of rows in section 5.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: it is crashing because because you need to update the tableView's datasource too. look at this post how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306792/uitableview-reload-section