# Why did the UITableView reloadSections crash on other section's row number changed?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my code , the number of rows for a specific section will change based on differenct condition :

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   
    NSInteger rowCount = 0;
    switch (section) {
        case QUESTION_DETAIL_SECTION_REDIRECT:
        {
            BOOL needTopCell = [self needTopOperationCell];
            if (needTopCell)
            {
                rowCount = 1;
            }
            break;
    
        }
        case QUESTION_DETAIL_SECTION_TAG:
        {
            if ([self.question.tags count] > 0)
            {
                rowCount = 1;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

If I call `reloadSections` with section `QUESTION_DETAIL_SECTION_REDIRECT`, the `numberOfRowsInSection` will also called for `QUESTION_DETAIL_SECTION_TAG` ,

And because the condition is changed , so the `numberOfRowsInSection` will change for section `QUESTION_DETAIL_SECTION_TAG`

but this will cause the tableView crash and complaints that

```
    invalid number of rows in section 2. The number of rows contained in an existing 
section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that 
section before the update (0)
```

And How to do this kind of reload without crash ?

#####Added more#######

I wrote a demo for this problem , and found the more exactly problem:

If you  call `reloadSection` for sectionA, the system will invoke `numberOfRowsInSection` for every section in the tableView , if any section except sectionA return a differenct row number with the value returned before , this crash will happen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UITableView reload section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306792/uitableview-reload-section)

Comment: Check @PtitXav link, I think the third answer is what you are looking for. From the docs: `At the conclusion of a block—that is, after endUpdates returns—the table view queries its data source and delegate as usual for row and section data. Thus the collection objects backing the table view should be updated to reflect the new or removed rows or sections.`

Comment: @GustavoConde thanks , because there are so many changes in my code , too difficult almost impossible for me to check insert or delete each time :) this answer seems not fit ro my situation

Comment: If you know that another section needs to be modified, why not also reloading this section in the reloadSection call ?

Comment: @PtitXav ,in fact, all my sections may changes , maybe reloadData will be my best choice otherthan reloadSections